# What is difference between Control.BeginInvoke() and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, invoke, begininvoke

Recently I used `Control.BeginInvoke()` method to put a method call into queue to be called on UI thread later. I also know there is `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` method. I read some general resources ([like this on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/159098/Control-Invoke-vs-Control-BeginInvoke)) and still have the question whether behavior of `Control.BeginInvoke()` is different from `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` or not.

I understand that analogical question can be asked for difference between `Control.Invoke()` and `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

Comment: There is no difference.  Use Control.BeginInvoke() in a Winforms app, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() in a WPF or Modern UI app.  Don't mix.

Comment: Thank you for clarification Hans. If you convert this comment into answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.BeginInvoke` existed from the early days of .NET (at least version 1.1). This is a very natural fit if you have an control and want to run something on its UI thread (there can be [several UI threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx)). However if you wanted to run something general on the UI thread and didn't have an appropriate `Control` the hacky solution was to create a `Control` which doesn't appear in the UI and then `Invoke` on that.

In .NET 3 (IIRC) `Dispatcher` was added to solve this problem.

In short:

- If you have a `Control` at hand you can use `Control.BeginInvoke`
- If you don't have an appropriate control, create a `Dispatcher` (in advance) and use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`
- If you're in the distant past, you have no option but to use `Control.BeginInvoke` :)